# Google Drive, Amazon AWS and other CDN very slow with dnscrypt-proxy

Tags: linux, networking, dns, amazon-web-services, internet-speed

On a pair of setup, I tested dnscrypt-proxy succesfully. The only problem that I've seen until now is the following:

Given that dnscrypt-proxy forwards the DNS requests to a server that is in a remote region compared to my provider DNS, all services that require a huge amount of servers likely using anycast ips (to make the data near the user) fails to identify my location sending me to servers close to the remote DNS server instead me.

Thus giving me a really slower speed compared to the ones that I could achieve connecting directly with normal DNS.

Examples:

- Amazon AWS or Wetransfer -> from 25-30MB/s in upload to 2.5 MB/s
- Google Drive -> from 30MB/s in upload to 3.5 MB/s

Is there something that I could do in order to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You could set your favorite servers in the configuration file.

See the article
[dnscrypt-proxy Configuration](https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy/wiki/Configuration),
section "An example, static server entry", where is described how to
edit the `dnscrypt-proxy.toml` file and set your servers in the
`server_names` field.

For finding candidate resolvers, see github
[Lists of public DNSCrypt and DoH servers](https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-resolvers).